# AspectJ aspect not called for loaded classes

Tags: aspectj

In a RCP osgi based application, i want to load classes from disc at runtime. This loading is independent from OSGI infrastructure.
I have a custom classloader, which can do this and works in general (without the AspectJ).

Now these loaded classes shall have aspects applied.

But the aspect code is not called.

1. I have the .class files build with Ant iajc compiler. Do I need load-time weaving?
2. When load-time weaving is needed, is it sufficient to add the dependency "org.aspectj.weaver" and make the classloader extend WeavingURLClassLoader?
3. If it is WeavingURLClassLoader, can i use this URL to point to an aspect, located in another plugin? "platform:/plugin/myplugin/my_package/Aspect.aj". Or without the .aj extension?
4. How can debug this?

Frank

.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working now.

using the ctor `WeavingURLClassLoader( classesUrls, aspectUrls, parent )`.

Where classesUrls needed to be a URLs to folder or Jar. This must include the aspectj runtime jar.

aspectUrls needed to be a URLs to folder or Jar. This must not include the aspectj runtime jar.

URL pointing to specific aspect files within the jars do not work. The trial to use a OSGI bundle URL, did not work. For me, i needed find the JAR files directly on the file system.